Cells are not evenly spaced when using rowspan within HTML table
I'm using rowspan on a HTML table with varying rows, however I'm experiencing an inconsistent cell height as screenshot. I would expect each cell to be evenly spaced, exactly like the row above - am I missing something or is this a quirk?



<style>
    table,
    th,
    td {
        border: 1px solid black;
    }
</style>

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Heading 1</th>
        <th>Heading 2</th>
        <th>Heading 3</th>
        <th>Heading 4</th>
        <th>Heading 5</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Row 1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Example</td>
            <td rowspan="3">Example</td>
            <td rowspan="3">A<br />
                B<br />
                C<br />
                D<br />
                E<br />
                F<br />
                G<br />
                H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">Row 2</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Example</td>
            <td rowspan="4">Example</td>
            <td rowspan="4">A<br />
                B<br />
                C<br />
                D<br />
                E<br />
                F<br />
                G<br />
                H</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">Row 3</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Example</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>




It needs to fill the remaining space caused by the last column. So this is expected.

While I do understand what you mean, why isn't the whitespace evenly distributed like the "Row 1" cells?

From what I gather from this proposal, Chrome's current table height distribution algorithm basically distributes extra space "greedily": first-come, first-serve. Firefox, for example, does distribute it evenly. It's unspecified so neither is technically better, although Firefox's approach looks better in my eyes.

It has an uneven number of rows to span; The cell with "Row 3" has rowspan="3", whereas the cell on the right, with "Example" has rowspan="2".

@HereticMonkey rowspan (and colspan) are supposed to ignore rows that don't exist. In this case, the rowspan="3" is larger than the number of rows, so it will behave as if it were 2 (changing it to 2 in the snippet will not affect the output, either).
